# jQuery.Deferred exception: data is not defined - ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I am having difficulties in creating dynamic elements to go into a div from the json values I get back when doing an api call using ajax.

The error I am getting in the console is:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: data is not defined ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous(file:///Users/ryanflanagan/iCloud%20Drive%20(Archive)/Desktop/devwork/lozfanpage/script.js:57:27)
    at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:30005)
    at t (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:30307) undefined
```

I'd say that I am pretty junior in my coding skills but hoping someone can help me on this.

This is my HTML

```
    <div class="container fluid charactercontainer">
      <div id="characterSearch" class="">
        <div class="innercontainer fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <aside class="col-sm-4 bg-light character-index">
              <h4>Search for a Zelda Character:</h4>
              <form
                class="form-inline form-group"
                id="character-form"
                style="width: 85%"
              >
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="characterinput" />
                <!--Button triggers character to be searched-->
                <button class="searchBtn2 btn btn-primary">
                  <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </button>
              </form>
            </aside>
            <div class="col-sm-8 border" id="characterInfoView">
              <!-- <h3 class="characterName"></h3>
              <p class="gender"></p>
              <p class="race"></p>
              <p class="char_description"></p>
              <p class="appearances"></p> -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And here is my searchCharacter function

```
function searchCharacter() {
  const characterInput = $("#characterinput").val();
  console.log(characterInput);

  const characterQueryURL =
      "https://zelda-api.apius.cc/api/characters?name=" + characterInput;
    console.log(characterQueryURL);

  $.ajax({
    url: characterQueryURL,
    method: "GET",
  }).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      $("#characterInfoView").empty();
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          console.log(data[i]);
          
          const column = $("<div>").addClass("col-sm-8");
          const card = $("<div>").addClass("card");
          const characterNameEl = $("<h3>")
            .addClass(".characterName")
            .text("Name: " + response.data[i].name);

          const charDescriptionEl = $("<p>")
            .addClass(".char_description")
            .text("Description: " + response.data[i].description);

          const genderEl = $("<p>")
            .addClass(".gender")
            .text("Gender: " + response.data[i].gender);

          const raceEl = $("<p>")
            .addClass(".race")
            .text("Race: " + response.data[i].race);

          const appearancesEl = $("<p>")
            .addClass(".appearances")
              .text("Appearances: " + response.data[i].appearances);
          
          card.append(characterNameEl);
          card.append(genderEl);
          card.append(raceEl);
          card.append(appearancesEl);
          card.append(charDescriptionEl);
          column.append(card);

          $("#characterInfoView").append(column);
          
      }
  });
}
```

With an event listener to trigger the function when clicked

```
$(".searchBtn2").on("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  searchCharacter();
});
```

I've tried putting in a parameter for the searchCharacter function like "response" or "data" or "characterInput".

But those don't work.

I can get the ajax call to work but nothing will show regarding the character's data points (race, gender, appearances, name, etc.) in the div block on my page.

Basically figured that I'd do a for loop as well so that I could create multiple cards in the characterInfoView div for characters that have multiple appearances as shown by multiple indices in the object's data array.

Using response.data[i].________ (race, gender, description, etc.) to bring in the json data for each specific indexed item as the loop is run.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {`.  There is no variable called `data` defined.  Did you mean `response`?  Maybe you need to `let data = JSON.parse(response);`?  What does your `console.log(response);` show?

Comment: //search value: Ganon             
//search URL: https://zelda-api.apius.cc/api/characters?name=Ganon.   

//{success: true, count: 3, data: Array(3)}.                            
count: 3
data: Array(3)
0: {appearances: Array(1), _id: "5f6d186f246bd9a0809d66fd", name: "Calamity Ganon", description: "Calamity Ganon is a recurring character in The Legend of Zelda series.↵", gender: "Neuter", …}
1: {appearances: Array(1), _id: "5f6d186f246bd9a0809d6404", name: "Yuga Ganon", description: "Yuga Ganon ...
2: {appearances: Array(13),...

Comment: I used 'data' as that was in the JSON object in the API where the data is. Interesting thing is when I console log 'response' instead of 'data' I don't get any jQuery error now but nothing is returned in the ajax call response in the console.log(response). Should the for loop be 'var i=0; i < response.data.length; i++'?

Comment: This is a URL that would show the json object for a character example: "https://zelda-api.apius.cc/api/characters?name=Midna". Just looking to figure out how to take those data points within each indexed item in the array and dynamically create it in a div on my html page.

Comment: In my for loop I've changed data.length to response.length and that removed the error!